# how do i can loop in the query sellctor all?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

heloo i have this code but when i click and genrate the new button its not  show in th "my3" varible in consloe

```
<body>

<button class="my-button" name="1">heloo</button>
<button class="my5-button" name="1">heloo</button>

<div class="container">

</div>

<script src="indx.js"></script>
```

and js code

```
let my = document.querySelector(".my-button");
let my2=document.querySelector(".container");
my.addEventListener("click",mm)
function mm(e){
let button = document.createElement("button");
button.classList.add("my2-button")
button.innerText="heloo"
my2.appendChild(button);
}

let my3= document.querySelectorAll(".my2-button");
console.log(my3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to console.log a variable that does not yet have content. Currently, the console.log(my3) fires when the page loads. At this point, "my3" does not have any content because the button was not clicked yet.

Instead, move the let my3 and console.log(my3) into the function mm. This way, every time you click the button, it will console.log the new value of my3.

```js
let my = document.querySelector(".my-button");
let my2=document.querySelector(".container");

my.addEventListener("click",mm);

function mm(e){
let button = document.createElement("button");
button.classList.add("my2-button");
button.innerText="heloo";
my2.appendChild(button);

let my3= document.querySelectorAll(".my2-button");
console.log(my3);
}
```

```html
<body>

<button class="my-button" name="1">heloo</button>
<button class="my5-button" name="1">heloo</button>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you found this answer useful don't forget to upvote or mark as accepted answer (=